# Multiple expressions with IN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-delete

I have two somewhat big (4+ million records) tables with identical structure, and they have about 300k duplicated rows. I'd like to `DELETE` the duplicate rows using the `DELETE IN` syntax.

I've already done it using the `MERGE` statement (available only on 2008 or newer, so I can't use it since I'm still running 2005), and the `DELETE EXISTS`, but I'm running into some trouble getting `DELETE IN` to work.

The problem that I'm having with `DELETE IN` is that my big table has a composite primary key, meaning I can only identify unique rows using all those columns together.

Is it possible in T-SQL to have multiple expressions as parameters to the `IN` clause? Something like:

```
DELETE FROM MyBigTable
WHERE ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3]) IN
    (SELECT [Column1],
            [Column2],
            [Column3]
     FROM MyBigTable
     INTERSECT
     SELECT [Column1],
            [Column2],
            [Column3]
     FROM MyOtherBigTable)
```

Comment: This is valid standard SQL syntax (if you replaced those square brackets with double quotes!) but is not yet supported in SQL Server, You can vote [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) for its inclusion.

Comment: If you want this syntax supported in a future version of SQL Server, please vote & comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just do a `JOIN` for this:

```
DELETE A
FROM MyBigTable A
INNER JOIN MyOtherBigTable B
ON A.Column1 = B.Column1 AND A.Column2 = B.Column2 AND A.Column3 = B.Column3
```